# Recursive query and summorize rows DB2

Tags: sql, sorting, recursion, db2

Hi I have the following table:

Table CODE

```
  A     B     C     D
test    10    1     NEW
test2   1     5     NEW
test3   5     2     OLD
test4   40    3     NEW
test5   8     7     NEW
test6   7     9     OLDER
```

The result should look like

```
  A        B      C     D      E
test     10      1     NEW    OLD
test2    1       5     NEW    OLD
test3    5       2     OLD
test4    40      3     NEW
test5    8       7     NEW   OLDER
test6    7       9     OLDER
```

Logics:

I check for C and see if that value is in B if D is NEW. If not it's done with that row.
If there is an entry I check if D is NEW and if so if the new C is in B in another row and so on until I find the C value as B with D NOT NEW.
I than need to take that Value and put it in the D column of the other rows affected by that saerch.

What I have:

```
with CODE (A, B, C, D, E) AS
(SELECT Original.A, Original.B, Original.C, Original.D, '' 
from myschema.basetable Original where Original.D = 'CORIPD'
UNION ALL
Select lookup.A, lookup.B, lookup.C, lookup.D, '' 
from CODE Original, myschema.basetable lookup 
where Original.A = lookup.A and Original.C =  lookup.B
UNION ALL
Select lookup_next.A, lookup_next.B, lookup_next.C, '' D, lookup_next.D E
from CODE Original, myschema.basetable lookup_next 
where Original.A = lookup_next.A and Original.C =  lookup_next.B and lookup_next.C IS NULL
)
select A, B, C, D, E from CODE 
order by A, C, D
```

The result so far:

```
  A        B      C     D      E
test     10      1     NEW    
test2    1       5     NEW    
test3    5       2     OLD
test3    5       2            OLD
test4    40      3     NEW
test5    8       7     NEW   
test6    7       9     OLDER
test6    7       9            OLDER
```

System is Windows IBM DB2 10.5

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution - I used rectest as table ame in my example

```
with temp (i,a,b,c,d,e) as (
select 1 as i, a,b,c,d, cast('-' as varchar(10)) as e
  from rectest 
 where D <> 'NEW'
union all
select t.i + 1 as i, r.a, r.b, r.c, r.d
     , case when t.i = 1 then t.d
            when t.i > 1 and t.e <> '-' then t.e
            else '-' 
       end as e            
  from temp t,
       rectest r
 where t.b = r.c
 and t.i < 5
)
, temp2 as (
select a,b,c,d,e from temp
)
select * from temp2
union all
select a,b,c,d, '-' as e from rectest 
 where a not in (select a from temp2) 
order by a;
```

The second CTE is only needed to get rows without a dependend row (which are not part of the recorsion - in your example test4.

Comment: It goes in the right direction but now the result table is :  
       A        B      C     D      E  
     test     10      1     OLD  
     test      1       5     OLD  
     test      10      1    OLDER  
     test1    1       5     OLDER  

It generates the outcome with all possible OLD versions.

Comment: Ok After adding r.a = t.a it works like a charm. Thanks for all your help.